# WP_Query custom post type query not showing the exact post type

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, customization

I am new in WordPress. I have registered `wp_query` function through 'custom post type UI' and 'Advanced custom fields' plugin. And this is the code in the portfolio page.

```
<div id="tf-content">
<div class="container"><!-- Container -->
    <div class="row"><!-- Row -->
        <?php
            $args = array(
                'post-type' => 'portfolio'
            );
            $query = new WP_Query( $args );
        ?>

        <?php if($query -> have_posts() ) : while( $query -> have_posts() ) : $query -> the_post(); ?>

        <a href= "<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-lg-3 col-xl-2">
                <div class="post-block" style= "margin: 0;"> <!-- Post #1-->
                    <div class="post-detail" style= "padding: 0;">
                        <div class="img-wrap">
                            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
        <?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

    </div><!-- end Row -->
</div><!-- End Container -->
```

I want this code to query all the 'portfolio' type custom post but I don't know why this code queries with general post but not portfolio type post. Please give me a solution for this.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The post type argument needs to be written as `post_type`, but you are using it as `post-type`.

Change your argument to this:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'portfolio'
);
```

Comment: Thanks Jack for the quick reply. I changed the arguments but I don't know why it doesn't work yet. Do you see any other problems in my code?

Comment: You're welcome. That's strange. Are you sure you are loading the proper page and template?

Comment: Yes.... but after changing the argument array into 'post_type' it doesn't even query among general posts though I don't want them. I want the code to query among only the portfolio type posts. Do you have any suggestion for me?

Comment: If it doesn't query anything, it means that `post_type` is working, but there might be a mistype, since it can't find the post type `portfolio`.

Comment: I think it is happening for registering the post type with plugins. I have used advanced custom fields and custom post type UI plugins to register the post type. And there the post type/slug is 'portfolio'. Do you have any suggestion regarding the mistypes that may happen by a beginner wp developer? Thank you.

Comment: Ohh!! Problem solved!! Actually, I forgot to set featured image so nothing was showing there. But can you please tell me how I can set the featured image as required because I don't want my clients to make this type of silly mistakes when I will become a pro and will start giving my services. Thank you for this support.

Comment: Glad to hear you've found the issue. WordPress itself does not have such feature. However, there are some plugins that can offer such option like [this one](https://wordpress.org/plugins/require-featured-image/) (I'm not affiliated with it in any way). You can also find some guides to do so, [this](http://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/require-featured-images-posts-wordpress/) one for example.